# Create function to run dictionary through glm regression analysis in R

Tags: r

I am playing around with creating a function, and was looking to create one that runs a glm regression analysis using a dictionary. Problem, I believe, is that the `paste` of the independent variable dictionary (maybe wrong use of the word here) is causing an error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = dep_var ~ iv_list2, data = df_bind,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'iv_list2')
```

Here is my code along with the fake dataset I am using. Should I be stripping the `""` before inserting into the `glm` line? Thanks for any help.

```
# Creating fake dataset
dep_var <- sample(0:1,20,replace=T)
x1 <- sample(0:1,20,replace=T)
x2 <- sample(0:1,20,replace=T)
x3 <- sample(0:1,20,replace=T)
x4 <- sample(0:1,20,replace=T)
df_bind <- as.data.frame(cbind(dep_var, x1, x2, x3, x4))

# Function to automate the glm code
my_function <- function(DV, IV, mydata){
  new_IV <- paste(IV, collapse = " + ") # Add the + for each independent variable
  glm_output <- glm(DV ~ new_IV, data = mydata, family = "binomial", drop.unused = FALSE)
  print(summary(glm_output))
  excel_output <- exp(cbind(OR = coef(glm_output), confint(glm_output)))
  write.csv(excel_output, file = "GLM Output.csv", row.names = FALSE)
}

# Independent variables dictionary
iv_list <- c("x1", "x2")

# Test the function
my_function(dep_var, iv_list, df_bind)
```

Comment: It seems inconsistent to try to pass in strings for the IVs but an actual variable for the DV. I'd switch to just using strings and rather than construct the RHS of the formula as a string, construct the full formula. `RHS = paste(IV, collapse = " + "); my_formula = as.formula(paste(DV, "~", RHS))`. Then call your function as `my_function("dep_var", iv_list, df_bind)`, using strings for both inputs.

Comment: Thank you. That works great. And yes, that was an oversight with the inconsistency in the DV and IV as strings. Posting with your code embedded as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Gregor the below edited code works now.

```
# Function to automate the glm code
my_function <- function(DV, IV, mydata){
  RHS = paste(IV, collapse = " + ")
  my_formula = as.formula(paste(DV, "~", RHS))
  glm_output <- glm(my_formula, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
  print(summary(glm_output))
  excel_output <- exp(cbind(OR = coef(glm_output), confint(glm_output)))
  write.csv(excel_output, file = "GLM Output.csv", row.names = FALSE)
}
```

And example of using the function:

```
# Independent variables dictionary
iv_list <- c("x1", "x2")
# Run function
my_function("dep_var", iv_list, df_bind)
```

Comment: or see `?reformulate` to replace the first couple of lines: `my_formula = reformulate(IV,response=DV)`